# How I can click a javaScript link in webbrowser

Tags: c#, javascript, browser

exp: `<td><input type="text" size="15" name="email" value="Email" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Email') { this.value=''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Email'; }"></td>`
I write there email these codes:
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
`
or

```
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
```

I write there these code

```
webBrowser1.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");
```

But

```
<a target="main" onmousedown="return false;"
   title="A collection of crimes you can do with other players [G]"
   href="./BeO/webroot/index.php?module=GroupCrimes" class="menuLink"
   accesskey="G">Group Crimes</a>
```

How can I click that link in webbrowser c#?

Comment: You'll need to provide further description of what you're after. You haven't provided enough information to be helped.

Comment: It isn't `onmousedown` but `onClick`. Still needs more information. What should the JS function attached to the click handler do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I click that link in webbrowser c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660213/how-can-i-click-that-link-in-webbrowser-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

You take your mouse. and you click the link.

[Group Crimes](http://s.tk)

Comment: hahaha. thx but if I click it myself, how I write that program?